# Loading MP4 files from Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app which is downloading several short `mp4` and `png` files from my server.

If I download them to `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` (`/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.config`) or `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` (`/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files`) and then navigate there using a root file explorer app, I can load the `png` files but not the `mp4` files, I get a generic playback error.

If I copy these files from either of the download directories to somewhere public on the device, such as `/sdcard/Movies` they load fine from the root explorer app.

Within my app, I am using `Android.Media.MediaPlayer` to load the `mp4` files but cannot load them presumably due to the same problem as what the root explorer app has above.

How can I play the files directly from `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`? Or where is the correct place to download them to for playback?

Comment: The comments on the accepted answer of the linked SO question are important as you need a seekable stream

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover I'll have a look